# Redis Cache as attribute .NET Core

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, redis, mediatr

Can I use Redis cache as attribute in controller? Project runtime setting is .NET Core 3.1.

This is my API example:

```
[SampleAttribute]
[Route("/user/getrosetteRewardStatu")]
[Authorize(Roles = "SelectedPos", AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BaseResponse<GetRosetteInfoResponse>), 200)]
[Consumes("application/json")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<GetrosetteRewardStatuResponse> GetrosetteRewardStatu()
{
    return await mediator.Send(new GetrosetteRewardStatuRequest() { CustomerCode = HttpContext.User.Claims.ToCustomerCode() });
}
```

For example how can I use `[SampleAttribute]` for caching? Do I have to write middleware for this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use redis for the response cache inside asp.net core? [Response Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/middleware?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i meant

Comment: You need write custom middleware to achieve your requirement. Like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KboCpJGa9ag)